# How emerge W(Transpose)diag in a derivative of this function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

in RNN  we have Back propagation Through Time (BPTT) Rule to  Calculate  Gradients for Loss function ( this descriptions isn't  important)

###### please say to me how this emerge

W<sup>T</sup>diag

in equation?

h<sub>m</sub> = tanh(U x<sub>m</sub> + W h<sub>m-1</sub>)

$\frac{\partial h_{m}}{\partial h_{m - 1}} = W^{T} \operatorname{diag} \left(1 - \tanh^2 \left(W h_{m - 1} + U x_{m}\right)\right)$

Comment: if $Y = AX$ and we are looking to differentiate $f(Y)$ with respect to $X$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = A^{\top}\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$. This should lead you to the $W^{\top}$ part immediately. The diag part comes from the differentiation of tanh activation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{x}_m+\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}_{m-1}$.

When a function $f$ is applied elementwise on a vector, e.g.
$\mathbf{h}_m = f(\mathbf{a})$,
the following differential holds $$
d\mathbf{h}_m 
= f'(\mathbf{a}) \odot d\mathbf{a}
= \mathrm{diag} \left[ f'(\mathbf{a}) \right] d\mathbf{a}
$$
where $f'$ is also applied elementwise and $\odot$ denotes Hadamard product.
In your expression, $\tanh$ plays the role of $f$ and it is well known that in this case $f'(x)=1-\tanh^2(x)$

Since you are differentiating wrt $\mathbf{h}_{m-1}$, it holds
$$
d\mathbf{h}_m = \mathrm{diag} \left[ f'(\mathbf{a}) \right] \mathbf{W} d\mathbf{h}_{m-1}
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{h}_{m}}{\partial \mathbf{h}_{m-1}}
= \mathrm{diag} \left[ f'(\mathbf{a}) \right] \mathbf{W}
$$
(which is the transpose of your expression).